# How to create LPAR/WPAR in linux?

Tags: linux

I am aware of creating LPARs via HMC and WPARs from LPAR on AIX

But, on my laptop (company owned), how can I create a WPAR (or) WPAR equivalent on RHEL 6

Comment: A brief google search suggests that a "WPAR" is something like a Linux container.  Use your favorite search engine to search for things like "docker" and "lxc".

Answer (score 0):

You can't create true Linux based WPARs, as this is something that is done within the AIX Virtual Machine (LPAR). Probably something that is like it in a way, is a Linux Docker host and containers (clients), in the same way WPAR uses related libraries for the versions of AIX in the WPAR host. Docker does this too, but in a more feature rich environment.
I recommend that you take a look at the '[Getting Started With Containers](https://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/)' page on the Docker website.
I myself run a VirtualBox VM inside my laptop as a Docker host enabling me to create many if not hundreds of docker containers.

Comment: Thank you, let me take a look on the URL which you pasted